Stutter caused by call to currentRenderPassDescriptor (currentDrawable/nextDrawable) blocking when MTKView is embedded in a SwiftUI app
I am embedding an MTKView via UIViewRepresentable in a SwiftUI app and put a SwiftUI interface on top. I am seeing this sometimes stuttering, even when only very lightweight render/UI work is performed, even on the iPhone 15 Pro, which should be more than capable rendering this at 60fps.
It seems this is always caused by SwiftUI doing a bit more heavy work on the main thread for 10-20ms. While this shouldn't be a problem, and just require to drop 1 or 2 frames, this sometimes would lead to a "frame traffic jam" for 100-200ms that looks like "wobbly 30-fps".
I am not doing anything out-of-the-ordinary, the code follows the sample code of the Metal game template in Xcode and what Apple does in the DisplayingAPointCloudUsingSceneDepth example project to use MTKView inside SwiftUI.
I created a SwiftUI example project that can be used to reproduce it: https://github.com/ralfebert/MetalSwiftUIExample/

It happens a lot more in my actual app which does a lot more rendering work and has a heavier SwiftUI View hierarchy on top. In the lighter example app I'd say it's no big issue, in a real app it definitively is.
But still, it can be reproduced in the example app: Drag the white cards a round interactively, flinch them, change the speed with the slider, just play around for a little while and the stutter will appear after a few seconds of doing that. It happens only on actual hardware, it seems to happen more on older hardware. One way that very often triggers is to put the app in background briefly and bringing it back.
Investigating this using Instruments, using the Hitches or Game performance templates:
Almost all of the time, all is well, and the view renders smoothly at 60fps. Here, the row on top is a signpost that wraps the whole draw method of the MTKViewDelegate. This is usually done in 1ms. The bottom row is the Display instrument with the display sync:

Sometimes, I am seeing the call to currentDrawable/nextDrawable (via currentRenderPassDescriptor) blocking for more than 16ms until the next frame:

And this seems to ripple through the next frames occasionally, unnecessarily blocking the main queue and causing stutter:

According to the Metal Best Practices Guide it blocks for getting the Drawable for the frame and there are only 3 of those according to the CAMetalLayer#maximumDrawableCount. But when rendering on the main thread, blocking the main thread like this when a frame takes longer and no Drawable is available seems rather unfortunate, because often there is other work to perform, and this work will have a tendency to pile up.
Has somebody seen this problem, too, and found a solution for it? How to render a MTKView with a UI built in SwiftUI on top at smooth frame rates?

Does the referenced sample code ever stutter?

While digging into this more, I found this thread on the Flutter repo that describe the exact same symptoms and a plausible theory of what's going on: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/48141#issuecomment-1817446598 . They resolved it by implementing their own CAMetalLayer-replacement 'FlutterMetalLayer'.

Also found this similar issue: Metal / UIKit synchronisation with .presentsWithTransaction

It helps to set the CAMetalLayer#presentsWithTransaction property property that's also available for MTKView.
This comes with a different procedure to commit/present as described in the docs:
commandBuffer.commit()
commandBuffer.waitUntilScheduled()
view.currentDrawable?.present()

While I don't care having perfect sync between Metal and SwiftUI, this seems to change the behaviour how late frames are handled.
Here is the example project with this change: https://github.com/ralfebert/MetalSwiftUIExample/compare/main...presentswithtransaction
While this very much improves the stutter, this doesn't fix the issue completely and the stutter still occurs, but with a lower likelihood.

The only workaround that I found that improves the visible performance in my app in addition to using presentsWithTransaction is to detect cases where the call to currentRenderPassDescriptor blocked and took longer than 10ms and then drop the next frame:
let start = DispatchTime.now()
guard let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else {
    return
}
let waitTime = Double(DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1_000_000
if waitTime > 10 {
    self.skipNextFrame = true
}

This is clearly not ideal, but it almost everytime prevents further damage and everything goes back to smooth 60fps quickly.

As a workaround, I tried keeping track of the number of drawables 'in-flight' by incrementing a counter when I got a drawable and decrementing it using 'Drawable#addPresentedHandler'. This surprisingly works well in my actual app, where this number was always 2 when the stalls would occur and I could then just not render a frame. But in the simpler example app, this doesn't work (number of drawables counted in this way doesn't predict the stalls reliably, it's also 2 when no stalls occur), I'm really puzzled why it might be different, but it makes this approach questionable.
I am wondering if there should be something like nextDrawableIfAvailable for CAMetalLayer that just returns nil if no Drawable is ready to draw into so that a frame can be dropped. Or a way to configure a very short timeout for allowsNextDrawableTimeout.

As an alternative workaround, when using CAMetalLayer + CADisplayLink directly instead of MTKView, one can get the targetTimestamp and comparing that to the actual presentation time via addPresentedHandler and drawable.presentedTime.
I couldn't find a way to predict if a Drawable would be available this way, so it would drop frames even in cases when a Drawable would have been available. Just observing my app in a very unscientific way, it didn't seem to help a lot.
Here is an example of a sketchy prototype of this approach: https://github.com/ralfebert/MetalSwiftUIExample/commit/16ea3c8f6d653d280d7f63a1b9742129a06d9ed0

I also tried using CAMetalDisplayLink as demonstrated in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/metal_sample_code_library/achieving_smooth_frame_rates_with_metal_s_display_link but in my app it would always have the worse performance characteristics of using MTKView.presentsWithTransaction = false. Maybe I didn't dig in deep enough here / missed something here - if somebody finds something that improves the performance for SwiftUI + Metal in cases where SwiftUI does a bit more heavy work on the main thread, I'd be very interested in hearing about it :)

I reported this to Apple:

FB13732234: Stutter caused by call to currentRenderPassDescriptor/currentDrawable blocking when MTKView is embedded in a SwiftUI app
FB13772824: Sample code on how to integrate CAMetalDisplayLink with SwiftUI apps


I'm having the same issue. Did you find any solution?
